# Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

Boa Noite!

Estou estudando a respeito de ASP.NET (venho do java) e estou um pouco confuso com tudo isso.

Estou tentando criar um endpoint para retornar a lista de clientes do meu banco de dados, porém, não consigo de forma nenhuma inicializa-lo!

Quando executo o projeto, o mesmo retorna o seguinte erro

```
exceptionMessage":"The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup
```

De acordo com os exemplos que achei, está tudo Ok, não consigo encontrar nada que me ajude com o erro em questão.

Gostaria também, se alguém souber de alguma fonte de exemplos ou tutoriais, como criar uma Interface para interagir entre as ações da controller e do banco!

Segue abaixo as classes do projeto

Webconfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

ClienteController

```
public class ClienteController : ApiController
{
    DbContext db = new DbContext();

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/{id:guid}", Name = "GetClientes")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetClientes(int? id)
    {
        return Ok(this.db.clientes.Where(c => c.usuarioId == id).ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/id/{id:guid}", Name = "GetClienteById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetClienteById(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "A Identificação do cliente é obrigatória.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Ok(this.db.clientes.FindAsync(id));
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
        : base("ResourceContext")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public static DbContext Create()
    {
        return new DbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Cliente> clientes { get; set; }
}
```

Cliente.Cs

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public int usuarioId { get; set; } //Foreign Key

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Cliente")]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string endereco { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(13)]
    public string telefone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(14)]
    public string celular { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Cadastro")]
    public DateTime dataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool ativo { get; set; }

}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //Token Consumption
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DbContext.Create);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o arquivo mais importante: `Global.asax.cs`.

De qualquer forma, este é um erro clássico do Web API. No Web API 2, o registro da configuração global mudou de forma. No arquivo `Global.asax.cs` do diretório raiz, evento `Application_Start`, troque:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Por:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Você pode ainda, opcionalmente, forçar a execução no seguinte como última linha do `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

Comment: no tutorial que segui ( http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ ) ele não utiliza a Global.asax.cs, ela é removida logo no inicio do tutorial, em vez disso, é utilizada a Startup.cs para rodar o projeto